# Inserting some Text to a View

Tags: android, listview

Im new to Android Programming. I just wanna know how to insert a Text into a View in Android? or if its impossible, how do I insert a string into a view? What im trying to do is to have a view with layout and text in it.

```
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

TextView tx = new TextView(this);
View vw;
Boolean hasRow = false;
ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);

tx.setText("asdasd");

if(hasRow){
    vw = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
} else {
    vw = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
}

lv.addFooterView(vw, tx.getText(), true);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My code lets me insert a view with layout but no text. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set text to `TextView` as footer of `ListView`. Use `TextView` from an inlated layout(row or row2).

```
if (hasRow){
    vw = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
} else {
    vw = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
}

TextView footTextView = vw.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_footer);
footTextView.setText("asdasd");
lv.addFooterView(vw);
```

Comment: what do you mean by txt_your_footer? is it just a textview?

Comment: It's id for TextView in row or row2 xml. I think you need to add TextView for footer – kimkevin just now